# Как сменить язык для всего приложения?

Tags: asp.net, локализация

Добрый день! Делаю программную смену языка как описано [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.90).aspx). Для чего создал отдельную страницу для смены языка, вот код:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"     CodeFile="ChangeLanguage.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>    
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>

<script runat="server">
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    If Request.Form("ListBox1") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim selectedLanguage As String = _
            Request.Form("ListBox1")
        UICulture = Request.Form("ListBox1")
        Culture = Request.Form("ListBox1")
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage)
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New  _
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage)
    End If
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub  
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="en" 
            Selected="True">English</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ru">Русский</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
        Text="Set Language" 
        meta:resourcekey="Button1" />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/default.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
    <br />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

На данной странице язык меняется нормально, но после перехода на любую другую страницу, язык сбрасывается на "по умолчанию". Что я не правильно делаю, как реализовать смену языка для всех страниц сразу?
.NET 4.0.
Web Developer 2010 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно на каждой странице переопределять InitializeCulture, либо сделать прослойку в виде базовой страницы и все остальные наследовать от неё.

Comment: Прошу по-подробнее.  
Если переопределять для каждой страницы, то где и как хранить настройки языка? Разве `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` не для всех страниц приложения? 
Прослойка это мастер-страница?

Comment: На мастер пейдже к сожалению нет данного метода для установки культуры. Нужно создать класс, наследник от Page (допустим BasePage), в нем переопределить данный метод, а все остальные страницы типа логин, рестрация и тд наследовать от етого BasePage. Хранить язык можно например в сессии. Что касается как: при выборе юзером языка, в сессию ложите выбранный язык и все, а в переопределенном методе InitializeCulture вытаскиваете нужную культуру не из ЛистБокса, как у вас сейчас, а из сессии.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Не наведете на материал о работе с сессиями?

Comment: В нете материала оооочень много, как и в каждой книге по асп - я прям растерялся что дать =) http://www.google.com.ua/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+session+

Comment: В простом случае все сводится к чему-то такому: Session("MyCulture") = "RU-ru" //положить в сессию нужную строку String c = Session().ToString() //достать строку из сессии, только еще проверку на нулл нужно перед доставанием.

Comment: Материалов действительно очень много. Пробовал с `Session`, не получилось, в одной статье прочитал, что это только для текущей страницы.  
Пользуюсь `Cache`, все страницы наследую от базовой, как вы описывали и все работает на ура. Вот только, после авторизации язык сбрасывается на по-умолчанию. И в Express версии Web Developer, все приходится делать руками.

Comment: Объект сессии для каждого юзера свой - только для текущей страницы это ViewState - с сессией должно все работать. Можно также хранить в кукисах выбранный язык. Что касается кеша, то он один для всего приложения и у вас получится ситуация, когда один юзер поменяет язык и у всех остальных он тоже изменится.